# Facebook extended permissions for users email address

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Currently I am using basic facebook permissions to get the logged in users id and username.  Which extended permission do I need to use to get the logged in users email address from facebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
email
```

Is the name of the permission. Here's the list of permissions: 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Answer (score -1):

```
    FB.login(function(response){
        if(response.status == 'connected'){
            alert('I am connected')
        }
    },{scope: 'email'});
```